# Not able to access the service menu on my Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, menu

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 from *US Cellular* and I'm trying to use it on a different carrier. I added the new SIM Card and I tried all the possible options to access the service menu and it always says ***"Mobile network not available"***. My phone model is SCH-R530U. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Samsung Galaxy S3 from US Cellular locked for US Cellular only? If YES, you won't be able to use a SIM card from a different carrier with it. You'll have to unlock the phone first so that it allows SIM cards from other networks.